# Generate combination of subset N from multiple lists

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I have 4 lists of elements and am trying to generate combinations of elements from those lists. Specifically, I'd like each combination to have 1 element from each list. However, I would only like each combination to have 3 elements in it. I would also like to record which elements are left out.

Example lists:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['m', 'n', 'o']
list3 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
list4 = ['q', 'r', 's']
```

Example desired output of just 2 rows but I would like all combinations:

```
combos = [[['a', 'm', 'x'], 'q'], 
          [['a', 'n', 'r'], 'z'], 
          [['s', 'z', 'o'], 'a']]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(combos, columns = ['combo', 'extra'])
```

Importantly, the "extras" should be sampled from all lists.

I am currently uncertain if order matters to me or not for the combinations, but if the code is easy to explain for permutations that would also be great. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?

Comment: Oh yes. Far too much. However, it seemed cleaner to post the most stripped down version since I was uncertain how to frame a question if I wasn't sure whether to use permutations, combinations, or product.

Comment: The stripped down version shows no attempts to solve the problem. It doesn’t need to be right, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```py
from itertools import product

ls = [list1, list2, list3, list4]

for *a, b in product(*ls):
    print(a, b)

['a', 'm', 'x'] q
['a', 'm', 'x'] r
['a', 'm', 'x'] s
['a', 'm', 'y'] q
['a', 'm', 'y'] r
```

Specifically to collect them:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[a, b] for *a, b in product(*ls)], 
    columns=['combo', 'extra']
)
```

## Edit

To swap which is the "extra", you'll want to permute `ls`:

```py
from itertools import permutations, product


ls = [list1, list2, list3, list4]

for l in permutations(ls):
    for *a, b in product(*l):
        print(a, b)
```

Comment: Hi! So that only samples list4 for the "extras". I need the extras to be generated from the other lists as well. For example, a combo could be generated from list1, list3, and list4 and the "extra" would then be selected from list2.

Comment: So in that case, there's a nested loop. You'll want to permute `ls`. I'll make en edit